# Website not loading properly on first visit

Tags: magento2, frontend, html

I developed a website on magento 2.2.2 (CE) which is running on managed cloud hosting.

link to website : https://i-ranu.com

all was going good but all of sudden am facing a wierd issue, that website does not load properly on first visit and slider and other product carousel don't load, but after reloading the same all works fine.

Please, any sort of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Porto theme issue. About the only way I could ever get around it was to merge/bundle javascript, which must be done in developer mode. It will work for a while without it, and then it doesn't. Seemed like it was a cache validation isssue for me, but never resolved using Porto without using merge/bundle js.